# Calculate Prorated Salary Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a table salary with sample data below:

```
affective_date  salary
7/2/2017       $250.00 
3/25/2018      $300.00 
3/29/2018      $350.00 
4/20/2018      $400.00
```

The sample monthly payroll is start from 3/23/2018 to 4/22/2018 and fixed 26 days per month.

I have manually calculated the prorated salary as below:

```
period          23.03-24.03 25.03-28.03 29.03-19.04 20.04-22.04
number of day             2           3          19           2
salary              $250.00     $300.00     $350.00     $400.00 
earn/day (x/26)       $9.62      $11.54      $13.46      $15.38 
earn/hour (x/26/8)    $1.20       $1.44       $1.68       $1.92 
total earn           $19.23      $34.62     $255.77      $30.77 
total prorated salary                                   $340.38
```

In this case, one month have more than 1 salary, so need to prorated based on working day.

My question is how could i create stored procedure in MySQL to get the result of total prorated salary?

Comment: you have your answer. just apply logic according to you description. i don't think you will face any problem. just take input whatever you want and return the salary after calculation.

Comment: @Paras thanks. anyway i dont know how to apply the logic to stored procedure in MySQL.

Comment: Is period really stored like that or is it stored as a date? What's the point of the earnings per hour row?

Comment: @P.Salmon period should be store as DATE. for earning for hour is extra for OT calculation.

Comment: Ok  sample payroll would be helpful

Comment: Or put another way without a sample payroll file it's impossible to supply an answer.

Comment: What are you counting as working days? If a working day is Monday - Friday then your "number of days" row in your data should read 1,3,21,1 because of the way the weekends fall. 26 is the number of Mon-Fri days in this period 23-03 to 22-04, but what happens in a short month? The equivalent dates for February-March would only get you a total of 20 days if the working week is Monday-Friday, how do you pro-rata different pay rates on n * 1/26 when there are only 20 days to work with?

Comment: @PaulCampbell the working day is Monday - Saturday and number of days is fixed 26 days/month as always x/26 to get earning per day. the actual working day is based on every month which could be 25. 26 or 27..final get earning per day multiply by actual working day.